# UIDragItem causes memory leak when Context Menu has been initialised

Tags: memory-leaks, uicollectionview, uikit, uicontextmenuconfiguration, uicollectionviewdragdelegate

I have a CollectionView with Drag and Drop and Context Menu functionality. There's a memory leak caused by returned [UIDragItem] array in ItemsForBeginning method when I initialise cell's context menu.

Objects are being kept in memory when I pop to rootViewController. All is OK though when drag session is being happened.

I've ended up commenting out everything, keeping blank UIDragItem and problem is still there:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider(object: "" as NSString))
    return [dragItem]
}
```

Does anybody experience this?
Looks like it's a UIKit bug...

Please help!

Comment: Have you ever resolved this?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for asking. Unfortunately no, I didn’t solve this issue. Maybe I’ll revisit it a bit later. Do have you have the same thing, right?

Comment: @badmetv Exactly. It's even reproducible with an empty cell content and blank `NSItemProvider`.